# EXcel formula : Summation based on same numeric input

Tags: excel

The requirement is that I have the following sample data in Excel 1

```
ticket      hours
----------+------    
1.131233    44   
2.12312     12    
3.131233    33
4.12312     12
```

In Excel 2 (different workbook),
we have the same layout, however there would be single entries for each ticket and the hours summed up corresponding to each ticket.

```
ticket      hours
---------+-------
1.12312     24  
2.131233    77
```

the formula that I have started with to sync any changes in excel1 to excel 2 is

```
=[Source.xlsx]Sheet1!$B:B
```

where source.xlsx is the excel1 
But, obviously this does not do any summation, just syncs data, I haven't been able to suitably modify this to fit my requirement.

### EDIT

Based on the given link I edited the formula

PFB the source and destination

[image]

destination with the new formula looks like below

[image]

the formula used is:

```
=SUMIFS('D:\Users\...\Desktop\POC - files\[Source.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:B,'D:\Users\...\Desktop\POC - files\[Source.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:A, B2)
```

Now this does not work, probably because of some silly issue, would be great if someone pointed out!

### EDIT

The below given formula does not work...
[image]

Also , this would do it only for one ticket, not for all tickets in the column A

### EDIT

Formula used

```
=SUMIFS('C:\Users\kphil\Desktop\POC\[source.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$65535,'C:\Users\kphil\Desktop\POC\[source.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$65535, A2)
```

[image]

Comment: Please see my edits , I guess, this is not exactly a duplicate here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your formula it should be A2 instead of B2 in Criteria1. The second formula is a sum product which will work when the workbook is closed.

```
=SUMIFS('D:\Users\...\Desktop\POC - files\[Source.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$65535,'D:\Users\...\Desktop\POC - files\[Source.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$65535, A2)


=SUMPRODUCT(('C:\Users\kphil\Desktop\POC\[source.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$65535=A2)*('C:\Users\kphil\Desktop\POC\[source.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$65535))
```

Comment: Nope, this does not work ...see the error it gives in the second edit section

Comment: Something is not right , the same destination file which was working before is giving an error! :( ///given it in the 3rd edit

Comment: If you are getting a #value! error make sure the ranges for A & B both start and end with the same row. If not what error are you getting?

Comment: Ahh, no its not that...i found it , the above error is also possible if there are blanks in the source or maybe text ...wow really took a while to get that one!  Its working again now. well thanks again ...lesson learned.

Comment: I also found that sumif doesn't work if the other workbook is closed. I've added a sumproduct formula to the answer that will.

Comment: Now, the second formula i suppose is the complete answer...yea i just tried out the scenario you mentioned ....i guess ill edit the previous formula

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Pivot - it is very easy once you get the hang of it. If you want to average your no of hours as against say sum, that can be done as well. (Or max/min/stdDev/etc) Here's a [link](http://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-summary-functions.html) that explains how. Once you are comfortable with playing around the labels, you'll not need to enter formulae ever again.

PS: would have said all this in a comment, but don't have the reputation (sorry!)